# How can the following integral be solved $\int t^3 e^{t^2+t} dt$?

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution

$$ \int t^3 e^{t^2+t} dt  $$Solve the given integral by using the substitution techniques or the integretion by parts

Comment: Did you try using a technique? If so, what were your findings?

Comment: I saw that the integration by parts was hopeles and ,in addition, i couldnt find a proper function ,to substitute with, so that i would manage to solve it.

Comment: By choosing which function to derivate?

Comment: Are you sure you're quoting the problem correctly? This integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t34.0-12/12248674_921095237960241_772713297_n.jpg?oh=9d385e6e619c67f23c0c4c2286fe3aa2&oe=564A9424

Answer (score 3):

First, we write the integral of interest as

$$\int t^3e^{t^2+1}\,dt=e^{-1/4}\int t^3e^{(t+1/2)^2}\,dt$$

Next, we make the substitution $u=t+1/2$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int t^3e^{t^2+1}\,dt&=e^{-1/4}\int (u-1/2)^3e^{u^2}\,du\\\\
&=e^{-1/4}\left(\int u^3e^{u^2}\,du-\frac32\int u^2e^{u^2}\,du+\frac34\int ue^{u^2}\,du-\frac18\int e^{u^2}\,du\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

We will use the designation $I_n=\int u^ne^{u^2}\,du$.  Then, using integration by parts on $I_3$ and $I_2$, we find

$$\begin{align}
I_3&=\frac12(u^2-1)e^{u^2}\\\\
I_2&=\frac12ue^{u^2}-\frac12\int e^{u^2}\,du\\\\
I_1&=\frac12 e^{u^2}\\\\
I_0&=\int e^{u^2}\,du
\end{align}$$

To finish, note that the [Imaginary Error Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), $\text{erfi}(u)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^u e^{t^2}\,dt$ so that we can write the indefinite integral

$$\int e^{u^2}\,du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erfi}(u)$$

Finally, we reverse the substitution and replace $u$ with $t+1/2$.  The details are left for the reader.